# Want HTML form submit to do nothing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, submit

I want an HTML form to do nothing after it has been submitted.

```
action=""
```

is no good because it causes the page to reload.

Basically, I want an Ajax function to be called whenever a button is pressed or someone hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the data. Yes, I could drop the form tag and add just call the function from the button's onclick event, but I also want the "hitting enter" functionality without getting all hackish.

Comment: "i also want the "hitting enter" functionality without getting all hackish." i think that ship has sailed after you have decided to have a form with action="". why not just wire up handlers for onclick events, and keypress events?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

By using `return false;` in the JavaScript code that you call from the submit button, you can stop the form from submitting.

Basically, you need the following HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then the supporting JavaScript code:

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
    function myFunction() {
        // Do stuff
    }
//--></script>
```

If you desire, you can also have certain conditions allow the script to submit the form:

```
<form onSubmit="return myFunction();">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Paired with:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
    function myFunction() {
        // Do stuff
        if (condition)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
//--></script>
```

Comment: Missing `function` keyword: `function myFunction() { }`

Comment: Is the myFunction() needed? In other words, can one not simply do <form onsubmit="return false;">  ?

Answer (score 20):

```
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="return false;">
```

is enough ...

Comment: I don't think it'll work over a POST FIELD specially using JS to submit the form; can you give us a **jsfiddle demo** please?

Comment: This worked for removing the need for e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 12):

It also works:

```
<form id='my_form' action="javascript:myFunction(); return false;">
```

Comment: Although that doesn't do nothing, it the console it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: You should add some explanation of what your solution does.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="the_ajax_call_function(); return false;">
 ......
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following HTML

```
<form onSubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). Maybe put a div around your elements from the form. Then use preventDefault() and then make your Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<form action='javascript:functionWithAjax("search");'>
  <input class="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" placeholder="input your keywords" type="search">
  <i class="iconfont icon-icon" onclick="functionWithAjax("search");"></i>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function functionWithAjax(type) {
    // Ajax action

    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You should really explain the code a bit.  It'll turn a good answer into a great one.

Answer (score 0):

In cases **where 'return false' doesn't do a thing,**

try just passing the `event` to the `form`'s `onsubmit` (not action!)

and simply add `event.preventDefault()` in that function.

*Leave the 'action' from the html. Additional info: action="javascript:etc(event)" didn't work in my tests.*

Answer (score -1):

As part of the button's onclick event, return false, which will stop the form from submitting.

I.e.:

```
function doFormStuff() {
    // Ajax function body here
    return false;
}
```

And just call that function on submit button click. There are many different ways.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the form's default submit behaviour from firing

```
form.addEventListener('submit', myHandler);


function myHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Just replace 'action=""' withonsubmit='return false'. That's it.

Comment: that answer was already provided!