# Stop textbox causing postback

Tags: html, input, textbox, hyperlink, postback

Hey. I've got an HTML textbox, but when I press enter, it causes a postback. I'd rather it either do nothing or 'click' a hyperlink anchor. How do I stop the textbox from causing a postback when the enter key is pressed? Tthanks

I have:

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" /> 
<a href="#">Locate</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384960/want-html-form-submit-to-do-nothing

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a javascript onSubmit handler that returns false.  E.g.

```
<form name="form1" onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" value="Parnsip, turnip" />
</form>
```