# When using AJAX and php with Google Maps, page keeps refreshing

Tags: ajax, google-maps

Good day all,

I have an html file as follows, which displays a Google Map (initialised at window.onload function) and has a form to enter the name of a place to search. When the submit button is clicked then user input is supposed to be sent to a php file which get the coordinates to display on the map. However, in testing, all the php file is returning right now is the same userinput.

The problem I am having, is that this sequence of event happens:

I enter some text, and click submit.
The p element innerHTML is changed and the alert appears (as in onreadystatechange function)
However, when i close the alert, the p element loses its data.

I added the alert, because when i just used

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

the p element took on its new data briefly before disappearing.

On thing i noticed was that while the alert was on the screen, the address bar displayed "filename.html". but when i closed it, and the p data disappeared, the address bar shows

```
filename.html?searchterm=user+input+stuff
```

Even when I click submit with the text input empty, I get "No Text Entered" appearing briefly, before the page "refreshes" then this text disappears, and the addressbar shows

```
filename.html?searchterm=
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Map</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylue.css" />   

<script type="text/javascript"      
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=AIzaSyBksQ7NlV6eXk6w5w8222lolqdPHsN_8ls&sensor=false">    
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">


var panorama;
var map;



function initialize() {

//create Google Map   
}

//other Google Maps functions   

function searchdb(userInput){

    var xmlhttp;    
    if (userInput==""){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="No Text Entered";
    }else{
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
  else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }


  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","searchpageajax.php?searchterm="+userInput,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
   }

}

window.onload= function () { 
    initialize(); 
} 


</script>


</head>
<body >

<h1>Map</h1>

<p>Enter a room code or building name to search.</p>

<form name="inputform" >
<input type="text" name="searchterm" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="searchdb(searchterm.value)"/>
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
<br/>
<p id ="msg"></p>
<br/>
</form>


<div id="container">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="streetview_canvas"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is refreshed because your onsubmit function does not return false.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384960/want-html-form-submit-to-do-nothing) (there are probably others).

Comment: This works for me. I feel like this is something basic, but I really did not know this. Thanks for your help.