# javascript to retain form on login failure

Tags: javascript, authentication

Below is my javascript function to authenticate a user... I wanna retain the form on login failure with the username/password textbox being blank.

```
           function authenticate(form)
      {
          if (form.username.value == "Administrator" && form.password.value == "password")
          {
             window.open('OrderList.aspx')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
         }
         else 
         {
             alert("Error Password or Username")
             $("#username").val("")
             $("#password").val("")
             form.????????????('Login.aspx')//so that it stays on the same page wihout reloading the page. 
I tried window.open, but it opens another instance of the form.
             /*displays error message*/
         }
     }
```

Comment: what triggers `authenticate`?

Comment: authenticate() is on the onclick of the submit button...

Comment: As an aside, it's considered a best practice to end your javascript lines with a `;` even though it isn't technically required. Doing so can avoid confusion in situations where code gets complicated, and helps a lot if you ever get into minification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are firing this either `onclick` or `onSubmit`. To help with preventing the form submission, you will want to use `onSubmit` and have it return the results of this function. In the case of a validation failure, your javascript function needs to `return false;` to prevent the form from being submitted.

When validation passes, you can either `return true;` or do nothing (assuming that you want the form to continue being submitted...if you only want to issue the call to `window.open()`, then you should `return false;` in both cases.

For a more detailed explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384960/want-html-form-submit-to-do-nothing/3384971#3384971) to a similar question.

As to removing the values from the text fields, what you have currently (e.g. the below code) will work for that - the only reason you aren't seeing the impact from it currently is that the page is reloading due to the form being submitted.

```
$("#username").val("");
$("#password").val("");
```

Comment: should i keep the onclick on the button or not? and what about emptying the textboxes?

Comment: See my edit. It's probably best to move this to `onSubmit` (which can be done in the html the same way `onClick` is assigned, but best practices generally dictate that you assign it to handle the `submit` event for this form instead. The code you already have empties the textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Handle `onSubmit` with your function and just `return false` - nothing will happen.

```
  function authenticate(form)
      {
          if (form.username.value == "Administrator" && form.password.value == "password")
          {
             window.open('OrderList.aspx')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
         }
         else 
         {
             alert("Error Password or Username")
             $("#username").val("")
             $("#password").val("")
            return false;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

As Dmitry said, you can do something like this:

```
$(form).on(
    'submit',
    function(){
        if (passwordsMatchOrWhatever){
            //do whatever a successful submission should
        } else {
            //reset field values if you want to
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

When the form is submitted, the 'submit' event is fired.  The code above uses jQuery to attach a function to run when that happens.  Returning false from that function cancels the whole submission.