# How do get an HTML form submit (and Python function return) to do nothing using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, flask

I am using Flask in a web app form on one HTML page, but spread out across a few 'pages' before submitting.

The first button 'Add animal' will run the `run_ME` function in my python script, and then continue onto the next page for the user to type in the animal name. My issue is, with Flask, I have to return something in my python function (I cannot return None or omit the return completely), but I do not want clicking 'Add animal' to cause the form to respond in any way, just run the function in Python and show the next page in HTML.

From [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384960/want-html-form-submit-to-do-nothing), I have added `return false` to my HTML script at the onClick event. However, this hasn't helped, and `return 'False'` in my python script (since I have to return something) overrides and gives me a blank page with 'False.'

Relevant code from HTML file:

```
<div class="section-25">
  <div class="container-5 w-container">
    <div class="text-block-6">Select the level of algorithm you&#x27;re looking to make</div>
    <div class="w-form">
      <form id="wf-form-Email-Form" name="wf-form-Email-Form" data-name="Email Form" method="post" action="">

        <!-- PAGE 1 -->
        <div id="page1" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">

          <!-- ALGORITHM NAME -->

          <label for="Algorithm-Name-3" class="custom-question algorithm-name">What will you name your algorithm?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Name" data-name="Algorithm Name"
            placeholder="Be as creative as you like!" id="Algorithm-Name">

          <!-- ALGORITHM DESCRIPTION -->

          <label for="Algorithm-Desc-3" class="custom-question algorithm-desc">Briefly describe what your algorithm does?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Description"
            data-name="Algorithm Description" placeholder="You can still be creative!" id="Algorithm-Desc">
          <p><input type="submit" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="C1" value="Add Animal" onClick="showLayer('page2'), runFunction(); return false;"></p>
        </div>

        <script>
          mybutton = document.getElementById("C1");

          function runFunction() {
            form.action = "/meta2sql";
            form.submit();
          }
        </script>

        <!-- PAGE 2 (1st ANIMAL) -->

        <div id="page2" class="page">

          <p style="font-family: Poppins,sans-serif; color: #fff;">1st Animal</p>

          <!-- 1ST ANIMAL NAME -->

          <label for="Enter-species" class="custom-question enter-species" id="one_name">What animal are you looking for?</label>
          <input type="text" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="species1" placeholder="Enter name of animal" id="Enter-species" required="">

          <br><br>

          <p><input type="button" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="B1" value="Go Back" onClick="showLayer('page1')">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
<script language="JavaScript">
  var currentLayer = 'page1';

  function showLayer(lyr) {
    hideLayer(currentLayer);
    document.getElementById(lyr)
      .style.visibility = 'visible';
    currentLayer = lyr;
  }

  function hideLayer(lyr) {
    document.getElementById(lyr).
    style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

  function showValues(form) {
    var values = '';
    var len = form.length - 1;
    //Leave off Submit Button
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (form[i].id.indexOf("C") != -1 ||
        form[i].id.indexOf("B") != -1)
        //Skip Continue and Back Buttons
        continue;
      values += form[i].id;
      values += ': ';
      values += form[i].value;
      values += '\n';
    }
    alert(values);
  }
</script>
```

Relevant code from Python file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect    

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/run_ME', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def run_ME():
  # some functions
    return 'False'

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: It will always respond with a HTTP response (status code + payload), Ideally you would render what you called "Next page" and return, or even better, create a http redirection for the "next page"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to return the `string` "False", but the Boolean value. Actually, if you want to do this 'properly', you'd return [server response 204](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204).

You can do this with `return Response(status=204)`
Of course, you must import that class from flask first.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I had already tried returning the boolean value but received `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a bool.`

Comment: I did however try `return Response(status=204)`. I tweaked it a little and what worked for me was `return '', 204`. Thank you for your help!